# Decoding Json in swift - Array but now a dictionary

Tags: json, swift

I previously decoded the following response correctly:

```
GET https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByNutrients?minCarbs=10&maxCarbs=50&number=2
[
    {
        "calories": 210,
        "carbs": "43g",
        "fat": "3g",
        "id": 90629,
        "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/90629-312x231.jpg",
        "imageType": "jpg",
        "protein": "1g",
        "title": "Baked Apples in White Wine"
    },
    {
        "calories": 226,
        "carbs": "33g",
        "fat": "10g",
        "id": 284420,
        "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/284420-312x231.jpg",
        "imageType": "jpg",
        "protein": "2g",
        "title": "Chocolate Silk Pie with Marshmallow Meringue"
    }
]
```

Using this codable model:

```
struct RecipieAPI: Codable  {
    var calories : Int
    var carbs : String
    var fat : String
    var id : Int
    var image : String
    var imageType : String
    var protein : String
    var title: String
}
```

However I am now using a different api endpoint with the following response:

```
GET https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?query=pasta&maxFat=25&number=2
{
    "offset": 0,
    "number": 2,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 716429,
            "calories": 584,
            "carbs": "84g",
            "fat": "20g",
            "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716429-312x231.jpg",
            "imageType": "jpg",
            "protein": "19g",
            "title": "Pasta with Garlic, Scallions, Cauliflower & Breadcrumbs"
        },
        {
            "id": 715538,
            "calories": 521,
            "carbs": "69g",
            "fat": "10g",
            "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715538-312x231.jpg",
            "imageType": "jpg",
            "protein": "35g",
            "title": "What to make for dinner tonight?? Bruschetta Style Pork & Pasta"
        }
    ],
    "totalResults": 86
}
```

And I am very unsure how I should change my code to get the array inside the dictionary appropriately. Any help would be really really appreciated :)

Note this is in my services class:

```
 AF.request("https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=\(NetworkServices.apiKey)&diet=Whole30&minCarbs=\(minCarbs)&maxCarbs=\(maxCarbs)&number=\(number)", method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let nutrients = try decoder.decode([RecipieAPI].self, from: data)
                        completionHandler(nutrients, nil)
                    } catch let error {
                        completionHandler(nil, error)
                    }
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
```

Link to documentation of api endpoints - sroll to bottom of page to see examples:

https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Recipes-by-Nutrients

https://spoonacular.com/food-api/docs#Search-Recipes-Complex

Answer (score 1):

Add the new root model with the nested key `results` which you were decoding previously

```
struct Root: Codable  {
  var results : [RecipieAPI]
} 

struct RecipieAPI: Codable  {
  var calories : Int?
  var carbs : String
  var fat : String
  var id : Int
  var image : String
  var imageType : String
  var protein : String
  var title: String
}
```

Then

```
let nutrients = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
completionHandler(nutrients.results, nil)
```

Comment: I get the following error with this: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "calories", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"calories\", intValue: nil) (\"calories\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: `calories` is not here in your respose json make it optional  try `var calories : Int?`

Comment: Then I have issues using item.calories in my view, however, there should always be a value for calories which is odd

Comment: And it also then asks the same for carbs